# event.target.value not working while setting the state for forms in my react code

Tags: reactjs, forms

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class FormsComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username: "",
            comments: "",
            topic: "React"
        }
    }

    handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onClick={this.handleUsernameChange}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FormsComponent
```

Comment: Either bind your `this.handleUsernameChange` in your constructor (which is not super great) or use an arrow function to preserve `this` (so `onClick={evt => this.handleUsernameChange(evt)}`). What you have right now won't even trigger your event handler, since it doesn't exist in global scope by the time it gets called.

Comment: try replacing `onClick` with `onChange`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think you got confused there, he is already using an arrow function when defining the handler

Answer (score 0):

convert this:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.username} onClick={this.handleUsernameChange}/>
```

to this:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={(e) => this.handleUsernameChange(e)}/>
```

Comment: edited my answer since i didn't realized this is an input field

Comment: The extra arrow function is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer since it helped the OP.

The proper event you want to bind to is the `change` event, so change your code to:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} />
```